# Is there a good way to apply a function cumulatively to a pandas series of strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame like this

```
   x  y
0  0  a
1  0  b
2  0  c
3  0  d
4  1  e
5  1  f
6  1  g
7  1  h
```

what I want to do is for each value of `x` to create a series which cumulatively concatenates the strings which have already appeared in `y` for that value of `x`. In other words, I want to get a Pandas series like this.

```
0          
1        a,
2      a,b,
3    a,b,c,
4          
5        e,
6      e,f,
7    e,f,g,
```

I can do it using a double for loop:

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
                    'y': ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']})

z = dat['x'].copy()
for i in range(dat.shape[0]):
    z[i] = ''
    for j in range(i):
        if dat['x'][j] == dat['x'][i]:
            z[i] += dat['y'][j] + ","
```

but I was wondering whether there is a quicker way? It seems that pandas `expanding().apply()` doesn't work for strings and it is an [open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23002). But perhaps there is an efficient way of doing it which doesn't involve `apply`?

Answer (score 4):

You can do with `shift` and `np.cumsum` in a custom function:

```
def myfun(x):
    y = x.shift()
    return np.cumsum(y.fillna('').add(',').mask(y.isna(),'')).str[:-1]
df.groupby("x")['y'].apply(myfun)
```

---

```
0         
1        a
2      a,b
3    a,b,c
4         
5        e
6      e,f
7    e,f,g
Name: y, dtype: object
```

Comment: I see, `np.cumsum` works for strings but `expanding` and `rolling` don't. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can `group` the dataframe by `x` then for each group in `x` we can `cumsum` and `shift` the column `y` and `update` the values in new column `cum_y` in `dat`

```
dat['cum_y'] = ''
for _, g in dat.groupby('x'):
    dat['cum_y'].update(g['y'].add(',').cumsum().shift().str[:-1])
```

---

```
>>> dat

   x  y  cum_y
0  0  a       
1  0  b      a
2  0  c    a,b
3  0  d  a,b,c
4  1  e       
5  1  f      e
6  1  g    e,f
7  1  h  e,f,g
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), adding `,`, cumulative sum and last remove trailing separator:

```
f = lambda x: (x.shift(fill_value='') + ',').cumsum()
dat['z'] = dat.groupby('x')['y'].transform(f).str.strip(',')
print (dat)
   x  y      z
0  0  a       
1  0  b      a
2  0  c    a,b
3  0  d  a,b,c
4  1  e       
5  1  f      e
6  1  g    e,f
7  1  h  e,f,g
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use lists here. Unsure for the efficiency anyway...

```
df.assign(y=df['y'].apply(lambda x: [x])).groupby('x')['y'].transform(
    lambda x: x.cumsum()).str.join(',')
```

It gives as expected:

```
0          a
1        a,b
2      a,b,c
3    a,b,c,d
4          e
5        e,f
6      e,f,g
7    e,f,g,h
Name: y, dtype: object
```

Comment: i2m afraid this is not exactly the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Can also do:

```
(df['y'].apply(list)
        .groupby(df['x'])
        .transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift(fill_value=''))
        .str.join(',')
)
```

---

Output:

```
0         
1        a
2      a,b
3    a,b,c
4         
5        e
6      e,f
7    e,f,g
Name: y, dtype: object
```